# VSCode extension add a input in activityBar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to add a custom form (`text input`, `submit button`) to the `activityBar`

[image]

just like the search

[image]

how is this possible with vscode extension api

Comment: I don't think it is possible with the extension API, unless you create a completely custom webview.

Comment: not all of the API for the activity bar Views is available in the extension API, I once asked to also allow to construct views like the breakpoint view, there is an isuue for that but it does not have enough +1's